# Using <h:selectBooleanCheckbox> with Map in a paginated <p:dataTable> throws NullPointerException

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces `<p:dataTable>` with pagination. I use `<h:selectBooleancheckbox>` with a `Map` property for corresponding row selection. The problem which I am facing is when I select and submit the values, there is a `NullPointerException`. The values are checked for particular rows only. I am using JSF 2.0 and PrimeFaces 3.0.

My page is:

```
<p:dataTable id="ngoPhotoTab" paginator="true" rows="10" value="#  {photoApprovelBean.lstNgoPhotos}" var="ngoPhoto">
    <p:column headerText="NgoName">
        #{ngoPhoto.ngoName}
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Select">
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="ngoSelect" layout="pageDirection" value="#{photoApprovelBean.checked[ngoPhoto.photo_id]}" />
    </p:column>
    <f:facet name="footer"> 
        <p:commandButton onclick="deletePhoto();" value="Delete" />
    </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>
```

Backing bean logic:

```
public class PhotoApprovelBean {

    public String deleteActPhoto() {
        List checkedItems = new ArrayList();

        try {
            for (Iterator<PhotoApprovelBean> itr = disAppPhotoList.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
                PhotoApprovelBean item = (PhotoApprovelBean) itr.next();

                if (checked.get(item.getPhotoId())) {
                    checkedItems.add(item.getPhotoId());
                }
            }

            toDeletePhoto(checkedItems);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public Map<Long, Boolean> checked = new HashMap<Long, Boolean>();

    public Map<Long, Boolean> getChecked() {
        return checked;
    }
}
```

The `NullPointerException` is caused in the line `if (checked.get(item.getPhotoId()))`. The The `Map` is filled with values of first page only. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got a `NullPointerException`, because the `if` statement expects a `boolean`, but the `Map` contains `Boolean` values only which can possibly be `null`. They will be `null` for other pages. The `Boolean` value of `null` can't be autoboxed to a `boolean`. You'd need to add a nullcheck.

```
Boolean itemChecked = checked.get(item.getPhotoId());

if (itemChecked != null && itemChecked) {
    // ...
}
```

Better, however, is to use PrimeFaces own `<p:column selectionMode="multiple">` instead. It will remember the selection on other pages. The `Map` approach is only suitable if you don't use pagination. See also [the showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf). Here's how it can look like for you:

```
<p:dataTable id="ngoPhotoTab" paginator="true" rows="10" 
    value="#{photoApprovelBean.lstNgoPhotos}" var="ngoPhoto"
    selection="#{photoApprovelBean.selectedNgoPhotos}" rowKey="#{ngoPhoto.photoId}"
>
    <p:column headerText="NgoName">
        #{ngoPhoto.ngoName}
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Select" selectionMode="multiple" />
    <f:facet name="footer"> 
        <p:commandButton onclick="deletePhoto();" value="Delete" />
    </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>
```

with

```
private PhotoApprovelBean[] selectedNgoPhotos;
```